# Xpath is correct still get no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My Xpath is correct & no iFrame and I can locate element in Chrome console but my program still fails. I have used explicit wait also.

website http://newtours.demoaut.com/
I am trying to locate login page and send login id.

Error message:

> PASSED: openURL
> FAILED: loginToTours
>
> **org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException**: **no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='userName']"}**
>
> *** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//input[@name='userName']}

```
 package SeleniumPracticePackage;
 import org.openqa.selenium.By;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
  import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
 import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait ;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Properties;
 import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
 import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;

 public class CallUrl {

WebDriver driver;
Properties prop;    

@BeforeTest
public void openBrowser() throws IOException
{

// driver = new ChromeDriver();

 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\Ashish\\Documents\\Selenium\\drivers\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
 //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "//src//test//resources//chromedriver_new.exe"));
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);     
}
@Test
public void openURL() throws IOException
{
//call URL from properties file
 prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream urlFile = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Ashish\\Documents\\Selenium\\SeleniumPracticeSite\\src\\URL.properties");
prop.load(urlFile); 
driver.get(prop.getProperty("URL"));
WebDriverWait myDynamicElement = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
myDynamicElement.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")));
}

@Test       
public void loginToTours () throws InterruptedException
{

  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")).click();
  //sendKeys(prop.getProperty("login"));

}   

}
```

TestNG XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <suite name = "Automation Practice Test">
    <test name ="smoke test">  
      <groups>
        <run>
          <include name="Priority2" />
        </run>
      </groups>
         <classes>
            <class name ="SeleniumPracticePackage.CallUrl" />
         </classes>
       </test>
   </suite>
```

Website HTML source code

```
                 <tr>
                  <td align="right"><font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="2">User 
                    Name: </font></td>
                  <td width="112">
                    <input type="text" name="userName" size="10">
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: I am at right page. I tested my xpath once selenium loaded the page. method to load URL is openURL() ... driver.get(prop.getProperty("URL"));

Comment: What's the XML that produces this message?

Comment: added xml in the last

Comment: Where is the `input` tag in your XML?

Comment: <input type="text" name="userName" size="10">  public website http://newtours.demoaut.com/

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the `.until()` line, run it, make sure everything looks OK, then step through the code. Does it work?

Comment: Yes... PASSED: openURL
FAILED: loginToTours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in your test code.

Explanation : You have two `@Test` methods in your test class. One of them opens up a URL and waits for an element to be present and the other method which just searches for the element. If TestNG ends up running your `loginToTours()` test method first, that is when you will see this error message. By default TestNG executes methods in an alphabetical order. Since `loginToTours()` doesn't specify in which web page the `findElement()` is to be located, Selenium ends up executing it on a blank page and thus you see  the error message. One of the fixes would be to have `loginToTours()` method depend on `openURL()` so that way there is already a valid web page opened up in the browser before the search happens. [ That is exactly what I have done in my cleaned up code as well ].

WebDriver is at no fault here :)

Here's a cleaned up version of your test code which will work fine

```
public class CallUrl {
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void openBrowser() throws IOException {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void cleanup() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void openURL() throws IOException {
        driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
        WebDriverWait myDynamicElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        myDynamicElement.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")));
    }

    @Test (dependsOnMethods = "openURL")
    public void loginToTours() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")).click();
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks , for the perfect answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your XPath is searching for an `input` tag, which is not present in your XML.

Comment: refer to input tag

Comment: Right, you need to specify the **exact XML** that you're parsing here.  The XML you said you are parsing does not have an input tag, and the input tag you just randomly put in the comment is not part of the XML in your question.

Comment: You are looking for xml used by TestNG or HTML/CSS code of website ? The one I pasted is HTML used the website and xml pasted in question is TestNG xml .. I have also given the link to the website

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue where I was not getting the value even though the XPath was valid (when entered in the inspect mode it was able to find elements). My code looked somewhat like the below -

```
driver.get("https://www.theurlgoeshere")
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='classname']")
for element in elements:
    element.send_keys("Test value")
driver.close()
```

For the above code, I encountered the error where the element is not found. In order to avoid this error, I have imported the "time" module and added a sleep time after the get statement, with this small modification the code worked.

```
driver.get("https://www.theurlgoeshere")
time.sleep(3)
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='classname']")
for element in elements:
element.send_keys("Test value")
driver.close()
```

As it goes on for parallel processing the driver tries to find the class even before it comes up on the dynamic page. The page has to load completely before it searched for the XPath within it.