# Unable Debug java selenium TestNG code line by line eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I know where my code has issue and I want to do **debug** it line-by-line to understand code flow. I know **F5,F6,F7** and step filter but I am still not able to debug it line by line as I

F7 -step return I get **Source not found**
I see cursor still on the same line 34

F6 - I again get Source not found
I see cursor still on the same line 34

to resolve Source not found I issue used 'Step filters' but in vain
still see new source not found messages and I cant see my execution line by line i.e. where is code going in every line. I can deal with source not found by just going back to my code and ignoring the new source not found window.

**I want to see program flow line by line**

```
public class CallUrl {
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void openBrowser() throws IOException {
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions");
 // BREAKPOINT BELOW    
 driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
}

@AfterClass
public void cleanup() {
    if (driver != null) {
        driver.quit();
    }
}

@Test
public void openURL() throws IOException {
    driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com/");
    WebDriverWait myDynamicElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    myDynamicElement.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")));
}

//@Test (dependsOnMethods = "openURL")
@Test 
public void loginToTours() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='userName']")).sendKeys("Tokci");
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Any one can help ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to debug the library code. Just step over anything that isn't yours and you shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: Your code doesn't really have any issues. I'm not sure why you are clicking an `INPUT` though. You should just use `.sendKeys()` to send the username to that field and move on.

Comment: code has issues refer to 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39561188/xpath-is-correct-still-get-no-such-element-unable-to-locate-element' Krishnan's answer

Comment: I wasn't looking at your TestNG declarations, I was talking about the Selenium code itself.

Comment: i keep getting error source not found.If I press F6 control moves to next line and F6 again, the complete programs runs. Attached screenshot